# Convert a future local DateTime into UTC

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone, exchangewebservices

I'm facing an issue converting a  EWS Appointment's start `DateTime` from the local time into UTC. From EWS, I get the Appointment's `DateTime` and `TimeZone`. I have been using `.ToUniversalTime()` to convert the `DateTime` to UTC.

However, when the current time and the Appointment's start time are on different sides of daylight savings time (for example, the start `DateTime` might be March 15, 2018), the `.ToUniversalTime()` conversion uses the *current* UTC offset, which results in a DateTime that is off by one hour.

I need some way of getting the UTC offset at a future date.

My best plan is to use `.ToUniversalTime()` to get an approximation of the correct UTC start `DateTime`. Most of the time, this will be the correct UTC conversion, and when it's not, it'll be close. Theoretically, I should be able to get a predicted UTC offset at this estimated UTC time, and reconvert the original start DateTime to UTC.

I'm aware this will fail if the start `DateTime` occurs within an hour after daylight savings time switches, but that's close enough for me. I would appreciate any suggestions or alternate methods, but what I'm really searching for is some way of getting the estimated UTC offset at some future date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things:

- `DateTime.ToUniversalTime()` can only convert from the system's local time zone.  It doesn't know anything about the time zone in your appointment.
- You are incorrect that it uses the current UTC offset.  It uses the offset in effect at the time provided.  Again, it only knows about the offset from the system's local time zone.

  - Note that if you are running on very old OS (Windows XP), it would only know about the current rule (for time zones that have changed their rules).  But this is all handled correctly in modern Windows.
- Instead of `.ToUniversalTime()`, consider using the the `TimeZoneInfo` object, and its `ConvertTimeToUtc` method.  Since you already have a time zone from EWS, this is likely the easiest route.
- The only "estimation" involved is that you are estimating the time zone rules won't change in the future.  This may or may not come to be.  Since we cannot see into the future, we cannot possibly know.   Your code itself does not need to do any estimation - the functions provided by the framework are precise enough, given the data they have available.
- There is already a *ton* of information on this subject here on StackOverflow.  Please search before asking.  Thanks.

Comment: Furthermore.... there is no way to do this before hand as the dates can change im the future and also apparently even after they occur if we so choose... silly humans....  this would require you to keep your own calendar system at a minima which knows both the official and unofficial savings times

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for the input. I did spend quite some time researching before posting here, but wasn't able to find a satisfactory answer. 

EWS returns a start time with a TimeZone that matches the client's computer. The Appointments I'm getting from EWS (including those in PDT) are being returned with the PST TimeZone. This was the source of my confusion.

However, the Start time is returned in UTC, and doesn't match the StartTimeZone given, so there's no conversion to do. The source of my actual issue is related, but can be resolved without conversion gymnastics.

Comment: Take a look at [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  In the section on Windows time zone names, you'll note that it mentions that just because you see "Pacific Standard Time" doesn't mean that PDT isn't taken into account when applicable.